# ps.executeUpdate(sql) throws com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm learning simple Database connection using mysql on Xampp server. Database is implemented on phpmyadmin. I'm accessing Database from java servlet in NetBeans IDE.

```
package com.DBcheck;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.sql.*;


public class NewServlet extends HttpServlet {


protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
       Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/profilebuilder","root","");

        String sql="insert into signupdetailstable(FirstName) values(?)";
        PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(sql);

        ps.setString(1, "nirmal");        
        int log=ps.executeUpdate(sql);
        out.println(log);
    }
}


@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        processRequest(request, response);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NewServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NewServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}


@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        processRequest(request, response);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NewServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NewServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}


@Override
public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description";
}// </editor-fold>

}
```

This code showing me error like

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?)' at line 1
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:360)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:978)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3887)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3823)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2526)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1618)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1549)
at com.DBcheck.NewServlet.processRequest(NewServlet.java:50)
at com.DBcheck.NewServlet.doGet(NewServlet.java:68)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Can anyone help what this exception is trying to say.?

Comment: Please don't use [servlets] tag as long as the very same problem is reproducible using a plain Java application class with `main()` method. This indicates that it has got nothing to do with specifically servlets.

Answer (score 0):

This is a **very** easy mistake to make. You're using `Statement#executeUpdate(String)` instead of `PreparedStatement#executeUpdate()`:

```
int log=ps.executeUpdate(sql);
// Remove this ----------^^^
```

Instead, you want:

```
int log=ps.executeUpdate();
// Nothing here ---------^
```

The only reason `PreparedStatement` has `executeUpdate(String)` is that it's a subclass of `Statement`. But with `PreparedStatement`, you supply the SQL when constructing the statement, which you've done correctly:

```
PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(sql);
```

And then you *don't* supply it to `executeUpdate`.

Comment: And yes, you might view this as a flaw in the API design. (I certainly do.)

Comment: Thanks for quick help. Your suggestion worked. @TJCrowder